# SQL Return the record where the value in a column have changed

Tags: sql, performance, hive, time-series

I have data in Hive table which look something like this -

| VIN | Mode | event | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Deauthorized | 01/01/2010 00:00:00 | 05/05/2014 14:54:54 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Deauthorized | 05/05/2014 14:54:54 | 05/13/2014 19:09:51 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Deauthorized | 05/13/2014 19:09:51 | 11/13/2014 22:26:32 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Authorized | 11/13/2014 22:26:32 | 11/13/2014 22:31:00 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Authorized | 11/13/2014 22:31:00 | 11/14/2014 01:23:56 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Deauthorized | 11/14/2014 01:23:56 | 11/18/2014 19:38:51 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Deauthorized | 11/18/2014 19:38:51 | 11/18/2014 19:38:54 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Deauthorized | 11/18/2014 19:38:54 | 11/18/2014 20:07:52 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized | 11/18/2014 20:07:52 | 12/17/2014 19:22:50 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized | 12/17/2014 19:22:50 | 02/25/2015 20:03:44 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized | 02/25/2015 20:03:44 | 02/25/2015 20:03:48 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Authorized | 02/25/2015 20:03:48 | 02/25/2015 20:14:05 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Deauthorized | 02/25/2015 20:14:05 | 02/25/2015 20:14:29 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Deauthorized | 02/25/2015 20:14:29 | 02/25/2015 20:40:21 |

I would like to get a summarized data where the value in event column has changed from previous value. The data points are in ascending order of the Start timestamp. I tried window function but it didn't work for me. The result would look similar to what I have shown in below table. Can you suggest any optimized solution for this?

| VIN | Mode | event | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Deauthorized | 01/01/2010 00:00:00 | 05/05/2014 14:54:54 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Authorized | 11/13/2014 22:26:32 | 11/13/2014 22:31:00 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Deauthorized | 11/14/2014 01:23:56 | 11/18/2014 19:38:51 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized | 11/18/2014 20:07:52 | 12/17/2014 19:22:50 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Deauthorized | 02/25/2015 20:14:05 | 02/25/2015 20:14:29 |

Comment: Hive != MySQL.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(event) over (partition by vin order by start) as prev_event
      from t
     ) t
where prev_event is null or prev_event <> event;
```

This looks at the changes by time and `vin`.  I'm not sure if the `mode` is relevant too.  If so, add it to the `partition by`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! While this very close to what I am looking for, I am not able to retain the first record with this approach. Any insights on how to retain the first record?

Comment: e.g. ABC123456789 Mode 1 Deauthorized 01/01/2010 00:00:00 05/05/2014 14:54:54

Comment: @Abhijit . . . I don't think you are implementing the logic in this answer.  It keeps the first row.