# How to retain the first record while using Window function LAG()?

Tags: sql, hive, common-table-expression

I have a data which looks like -

**Actual Table -**

| VIN | Mode | Status | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Waiting for Auth | 01/01/2010 00:00:00 | 05/05/2014 14:54:54 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Waiting for URL | 05/05/2014 14:54:54 | 05/13/2014 19:09:51 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Waiting for User | 05/13/2014 19:09:51 | 11/13/2014 22:26:32 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Authorized | 11/13/2014 22:26:32 | 11/13/2014 22:31:00 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Authorized | 11/13/2014 22:31:00 | 11/14/2014 01:23:56 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Waiting for User | 11/14/2014 01:23:56 | 11/18/2014 19:38:51 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Waiting for User | 11/18/2014 19:38:51 | 11/18/2014 19:38:54 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Waiting for User | 11/18/2014 19:38:54 | 11/18/2014 20:07:52 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized All | 11/18/2014 20:07:52 | 12/17/2014 19:22:50 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized All | 12/17/2014 19:22:50 | 02/25/2015 20:03:44 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized All | 02/25/2015 20:03:44 | 02/25/2015 20:03:48 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Authorized All | 02/25/2015 20:03:48 | 02/25/2015 20:14:05 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Revoke Auth | 02/25/2015 20:14:05 | 02/25/2015 20:14:29 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Waiting for Auth | 02/25/2015 20:14:29 | 02/25/2015 20:40:21 |

I am using the below window function query to get the expected result as shown in the result output table. ***But I am not able to retain the first row.*** How to achieve it?

**Hive Query -**

```
WITH mma AS
(
select VIN, 
       Mode, 
       Status,
       case when lower(Status) like '%authorized%' then 'Authorized' else 'Deauthorized' end Event,
       Start, 
       End 
  from ModemAuth 
 where VIN = 'ABC123456789'
 order by Start
 )

select mma2.*
from (select mma.*,
             lag(event) over (partition by VIN order by Start) as Prev_Event
        from mma
     ) mma2
where Prev_Event <> Event
```

**Expected Result** -

| VIN | Mode | Status | Event | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Waiting for Auth | Deauthorized | 01/01/2010 00:00:00 | 05/05/2014 14:54:54 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 1 | Authorized | Authorized | 11/13/2014 22:26:32 | 11/13/2014 22:31:00 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Waiting for User | Deauthorized | 11/14/2014 01:23:56 | 11/18/2014 19:38:51 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 2 | Authorized All | Authorized | 11/18/2014 20:07:52 | 12/17/2014 19:22:50 |
| ABC123456789 | Mode 3 | Revoke Auth | Deauthorized | 02/25/2015 20:14:05 | 02/25/2015 20:14:29 |

Comment: what do you mean by retain the first row? what are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` condition is not correct.  It should be:

```
where Prev_Event is null or prev_event <> Event
```

This is the logic I put on your previous, similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211961/sql-return-the-record-where-the-value-in-a-column-have-changed).  You can accept that answer.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I completely missed the NULL condition from your previous solution. This is very helpful. I am accepting both solutions.